# Add dependencies automatically to a new solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm currently working on a .net product with a large amount of project files, added to the main solution. My part of the project is focused inside one of the projects, however the amount of code drags down build and test time.
I would like to create a new solution, include the project I'm working in and add all project references.
Is there a third party tool, or an easy way to recursively add all project references to a newly created solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new solution with just your project and dependant projects have built before in that workspace, you can build your project and ignore the other projects.